# Don't want provider to create new instance each time while using Google Guice Dependency Injection

Tags: scala, dependencies, guice, akka-stream, akka-http

I.m new to Google Guice Dependency Injection. I'm implementing (Provider), but it's making new instance each time. I want it to use same instance of StudentRepository Class which it was created first time using Provider.

StudentRepositoryTrait Code:

```
package repository

import akka.Done
import models.Student

trait StudentRepositoryTrait {
  def fetchStudent(studentEmail: String): Option[(String, Student)]

  def saveStudent(student: Student): Done
}
```

StudentRepository Class:

```
package repository.implementation

import akka.Done
import models.Student
import practice.LoggerFactoryObject.log
import repository.StudentRepositoryTrait
import scala.collection.mutable

class StudentRepository extends StudentRepositoryTrait {
  val studentsData = mutable.Map[String, Student]()

  def fetchStudent(studentEmail: String): Option[(String, Student)] = {
    studentsData.find(_._1 == studentEmail)
  }


  def saveStudent(student: Student): Done = {
    studentsData += (student.email -> student)
    Done
  }

}
```

StudentServiceTrait Code:

```
package service

import akka.Done
import models.Student

trait StudentServiceTrait {
  def fetchStudent(studentEmail: String): Option[(String, Student)]

  def saveStudent(student: Student): Done
}
```

StudentService Class:

```
package service.implementation

import akka.Done
import com.google.inject.{Inject, Provider}
import models.Student
import repository.StudentRepositoryTrait
import service.StudentServiceTrait

class StudentService @Inject() (studentRepositoryTrait: Provider[StudentRepositoryTrait]) extends StudentServiceTrait {
  def fetchStudent(studentEmail: String): Option[(String, Student)] = {
    studentRepositoryTrait.get().fetchStudent(studentEmail)
  }

  def saveStudent(student: Student): Done = {
    studentRepositoryTrait.get().saveStudent(student)
  }
}
```

Provider Class:

```
package providers

import com.google.inject.Provider
import repository.StudentRepositoryTrait

class StudentRepositoryTraitProvider extends Provider[StudentRepositoryTrait] {
  private var studentRepository : StudentRepositoryTrait = null

  override def get(): StudentRepositoryTrait = {
    if(studentRepository == null)
      studentRepository = new StudentRepository

    studentRepository
  }

}
```

Module Class:

```
package modules

import com.google.inject.AbstractModule
import providers.StudentRepositoryTraitProvider
import repository.StudentRepositoryTrait

class StudentGuiceModule extends AbstractModule{
  override def configure(): Unit = {
    bind(classOf[StudentRepositoryTrait]).toProvider(classOf[StudentRepositoryTraitProvider])
  }

}
```

The main issue is I'm using akka-http, and in Controller class I've two routes. One route is for getting Post request and save student data into map(which is in StudentRepository Class), other route is for Get request which gets data from map and send that data in response. Now the problem is provider is making new instance of StudentRepository each time, so when first time on Post Request data is saved in studentsMap, then when a Get Request come due to new Instance I am not able to get that data which I stored previously. Kindly help me in that.

Comment: What have you tried to debug this so far?

Comment: On top of my head: you didn't declare the provider as a singleton, not entirely sure it's by default. The provider is using a `var` with no thread safety.

Comment: Also I guess you simplified the code but I don't see any reason to use a `Provider` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Your Provider class could be simplified to:

```
object StudentRepositoryTraitProvider extends Provider[StudentRepositoryTrait] {
  val studentRepository = new StudentRepository

  override def get(): StudentRepositoryTrait = studentRepository   
}
```